# In SQL, how to find customer IDs who are only 5 particular products or a combination of them

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table with Customer_ID and Product_Code. Customer IDs are unique for each customer and they have multiple rows for each transaction. I want to find the Customer IDs that are only buying product A, B, C, D, E pr their combination. If someone is buying A and X, I don't want to pull that Customer ID.

I tried using `case when Product Code in (A,B,C,D,E) then 'OK' else 'Not OK' end as 'Flag'` but that does not give me an accurate result as it gives me Customer_IDs that are buying these product along with X, Y, Z etc.

Comment: provide some sample data

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a query that finds the customers who have bought products outside that set, and then exclude them.

```
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM purchase
WHERE Customer_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID
    FROM purchase
    WHERE product_code NOT IN (A, B, C, D, E)
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was actually joining multiple tables since yesterday and was trying to achieve this in the join query itself. Created a table so it would be easier to explain here and used your query - it did wonders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select customerid,
       (case when sum(case when Product Code not in (A, B, C, D, E) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Not OK'
             else 'OK'
        end) as flag
from t
group by customerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using not exists -

```
select distinct customer_id from tablename t
where not exists 
(select 1 from tablename t1 where t.customer_id=t1.customer_id
    and t1.product_code not in (A,B,C,D,E))
and t.product_code in (A,B,C,D,E)
```